# how to call URL from local env in Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i have an issue on my code (Weather App using OpenWeahterMap Api) after i tried to move my apiKey and apiUrl to the .env file, i already got this error in the terminal and it's not clear why its happend

here is my code :

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const { restart } = require("nodemon");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css'));

    // The app will redirect to index.html page
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
})

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
    
    dotenv.config({ path: '/.env' });
    require('dotenv').config();

    const weatherUrl = process.env.API_URL;
    const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY;
    const city = req.body.cityName;
    const unit = "metric";

    const url = weatherUrl + city + "&appid=" + apiKey + "&units=" + unit

    // the response will recive the data and will parse the jsonData from the API
    // and will print the the current temprerature + description + weather icon 
    https.get(url, function(response){

        response.on("data", function(data){
            const weatherData = JSON.parse((data)); 
            const temp = weatherData.main.temp;
            const weatherDescription = weatherData.weather[0].description;
            const weatherIcon = weatherData.weather[0].icon;
            const imageUrl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + weatherIcon + "@2x.png"

            res.write("<p>The Weather is currently " + weatherDescription + "</p>");
            res.write("<h1>The temprerature in" + city + "now is "+ temp + " degress Celcius.</h1>");
            res.write("<img src=" + imageUrl + ">");
            res.send();
        })
    })
})

    // default port can be change 
app.listen(3333, function() {
    console.log("Server is running on port 3333");
});
```

the error message :

```
Server is running on port 3333
/Programming/JS/WeatherApp/app.js:35
            const temp = weatherData.main.temp;
                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined
```

i am not sure where is exactly the problem because it's first time i am using Express JS

Comment: what does `console.log(typeof weatherData, weatherData)` show?

Comment: `path: '/.env'` is from the root directory. Did you mean `./.env`?

Comment: the console.log(typeof weatherData, weatherData) is 

Server is running on port 3333
object {
  cod: 401,
  message: 'Invalid API key. Please see https://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info.'
}

Comment: the Api is working via Postman and i can get it as JSON Object

Comment: ... Did you check that your `.env` file is being loaded, like by logging? What debugging steps have you taken? Did you read my comment regarding the `.env` file location?

Comment: yes exactly its from the root direcotry 
path: '/.env' is from the root directory. Did you mean ./.env?

Comment: How did you guys format the code inside of your comment? ctrl + k makes me type into the browser

Comment: @devin With single backticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to identify where your path is for your .env file if it is in the same directory as this file then you need to put `./.env` if it is in a directory above this one you need to put `../.env` or two directories `../../.env.` `/.env` doesn't mean anything

The .env file should also not have semi colons to delimit the end of your keys.

Comment: i understand that and i changed the path of env file to correct one but i still one code 401 message Invalid API key !!

Comment: Do this for me: 
    `dotenv.config({ path: '/.env' });`
    `require('dotenv').config();`

   `const weatherUrl = process.env.API_URL`

    `console.log(weatherUrl);`

Comment: tell me if the console.log(weatherUrl) actually prints it out to the console

Comment: @Darkhole can you tell me the file structure of your project in your question:


`app --> ['.env','server.js']`

is that the structure?

Comment: the console.log is https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=; - its seems like cant read or call the api key from the .env file ? or ?

Comment: yes that is the structure.

Comment: delete the current dotenv code you have and add this to the top of your file:

`require("dotenv").config();`

Comment: And also make sure you have installed dotenv: npm install dotenv

Comment: If you need further help join my discord: https://discord.gg/zMDqtUv9